# Visual Studio LightSwitch HTML project will not deploy database schema to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio-lightswitch

I ran into deployment issues, so I created a test app to prove out the deployment process. I've kept everything as "out of the box" as possible:

- I've created a simple (one table and one screen) VS2013 LightSwitch HTML client app, but the deployment fails, because it will not deploy the database schema.
- I've created the Azure website and linked it to my Azure SQL Database, also the "Deploy database schema" checkbox is checked in the wizard.

It seems that my only option at the moment is to manually create the DB objects, which seems kind of absurd.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to this issue. 
It seems that the problem stems from not having the deployment credentials. What I have found is that if I attempt to deploy the server project there is a drop down list box that's supposed to be populated with available destinations. At the first attempt the list comes up blank but if I proceed to publish a message flashes up confirming a new set of credentials has been downloaded. After that I found I am able to publish the main project itself database objects as well.

In short; make sure you are properly logged in even if you have to log out and then in again, and also have deployment credentials up to date.